# How to find and open images? using cordova-plugin-file

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I have an application that downloads compressed images, I am able to download and unzip the images and delete the zip file, but I cannot display the uncompressed images in my application.

I can locate the images when connected the device to the computer via USB

But my app can't show the images using `<img src="">` Even when I know the location of the images they are not displayed. I'm tired of searching and I can't understand how to show these images.

I already tried all Android File System Layout settings:
*applicationDirectory,
applicationStorageDirectory,
cacheDirectory,
dataDirectory*

Anyone had this problem and managed to solve it?

I using: Cordova 10 and cordova-plugin-file v6.0.2. I was using *cordova.file.externalDataDirectory* and the *///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app.id>/files/* to show images

Comment: You need to paste some version and code here

Comment: I using: Cordova 10 and cordova-plugin-file v6.0.2. I was using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory and the ///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.id/files/ to show images